# Ubuntu 13.04 has a bottom taskbar - how can I get rid of it?

Tags: gnome, 13.04

What is the new task bar at the bottom of the screen in Ubuntu 13.04 it hangs the system while its up and how do I get rid of it?

Comment: What task bar are you talking about. In Ubuntu there is no task bar at the bottom. Can you provide an image?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you are using GNOME given the tag.

Right-click on the "task bar", select **delete this panel**, click **delete**.